# MYSQL Date before today

Tags: mysql, date, select, intervals, dateinterval

This has been asked quite alot but the answer i found dont seem to work, so im posting here to see if someone can help.

I have this

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(order_date) AS order_date, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(order_expected) AS order_expected
            FROM orders WHERE DATE(order_expected) BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(order_date) AS order_date, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(order_expected) AS order_expected
                FROM orders WHERE DATE(order_expected) BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY);
```

all fields are name correct but neither seem to be able to get a value with its date within 7 days before today.

Please help.

Ian

Comment: Swap the dates around. Have the smaller (ie, 7 days prior to today) first

Answer (score 4):

Try this:-

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(order_date) AS order_date, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(order_expected) AS order_expected
FROM orders 
WHERE DATE(order_expected) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND NOW()
```